# Markov states probability of at least one state event.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Assume that we have $S_n$ Markov chain with transition matrix $P$. Assume that $S_n \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$ and we have $\tau \in \mathbb{N}$.

We want to estimate probability $\mathbb{P}(S_{n+1} = k \lor \ldots \lor S_{n+\tau} = k | S_n = i)$. It's not hard to get $\mathbb{P}(S_{n+m} = k | S_n = i)$ using matrix. But what about the event there is at least one $m:$ $S_{n+m} = k$? Looks like inclusion-exclusion but in hard manner. Any ideas?

Comment: The probability of "the event there is at least one" is $1$ minus the probability of "the event there are none".

Comment: Or change your transition matrix to make $k$ an absorbing state by making the final row $(0 \quad 0 \quad \cdots \quad 0 \quad 1)$.

Comment: @Henry an excellent idea with transition matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
T_t=\cases{k&if $\ S_j=k\ \ \text{ for some }\ \ j\ \ \text{ with }\ \ n+1\le j\le t$\\
S_t&otherwise.}
$$
Then $\ T_t\ $ is a (time-inhomogeneous) Markov chain for which the state $\ k\ $ becomes absorbing after time $\ t=n\ $, and for which we have the identity
$$
\bigvee_{j=1}^m\big\{S_{n+j}=k\big\}=\big\{T_{n+m}=k\big\}
$$
For $\ t\ge n+1\ $, the transition matrix $\ \widehat{P}\ $ of $\ T_t\ $ is given by
$$
\widehat{P}_{ij}=\cases{P_{ij}&if $\ i\ne k$\\
1&if $\ i=j=k$\\
0&if $\ i=k,j\ne k$ .}
$$
We then have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\left.\bigvee_{j=1}^m\big\{S_{n+j}=k\big\}\right|S_n=i\right)&=\mathbb{P}\big(T_m=k\big|S_n=i\big)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\big(T_m=k\big|T_n=i\big)\\
&=\epsilon_i^TP\widehat{P}^{m-n-1}\epsilon_k\ ,
\end{align}
where, for each $\ i\ $, $\ \epsilon_i\ $ is the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ column of the $\ k\times k\ $ identity matrix.